# Is it possible to plot a plane by it's equation f(x) + g(y) + h(z) + c = 0?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Is it possible to plot a plane, given the equation

```
x^2 + y^2 - 1.6z^2 + 1 = 0
```

with R?

It should look like this:

[image]

(Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zweischaliges_Hyperboloid.png)

### What I've tried

```
library(rgl)
x = -20:20
xs = rep(x, 40)
y = -20:20
ys = rep(y, each=40)
z = (-(-1-x^2-y^2)/1.6)^0.5
plot3d(x=xs, y=ys, z=z)
```

This does plot the upper part, but I would like to see the lower part, too. Also, the plot doesn't look nice.

Comment: Doable in the `rgl` package in full 3d rotational glory...

Comment: @Spacedman; easy for one of the surfaces `zfun <- function(x,y) (-(-1-x^2-y^2)/1.6)^0.5; persp3d(zfun, c(-20,20), c(-20,20))`. I can't immediately see how to add the second surface. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question I posed in my comment and providing what I think is a complete answer using `rgl`

```
library(rgl)
# define +ve function and plot it
zfun <- function(x,y) (-(-1-x^2-y^2)/1.6)^0.5 
persp3d(zfun, c(-20,20), c(-20,20), n = 101)
# define x-y grid for second surface
xyvec <- seq(-20, 20, length.out = 101)
# calculate surface as -ve function and plot it
zmat <- -outer(xyvec, xyvec, zfun)
surface3d(xyvec, xyvec, zmat)
```